# Create symlinks from files in new folder, but not folders

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I would like to create symlinks from all files and files in the sub-folders in a new folder.
So, it makes a new folder, and in this new folder it mirrors the actual folder structure from the source folder (real folders, no symlinks) and creates symlinks to all files.
Like this:

source folder

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder3/file1
file2
```

new folder

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder3/symlink: file1
symlink: file2
```

I heard of "recursive" but I don't know how to do that in debian.
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-s` parameter of `cp`:

```
cp -rs /source/dir/* /target/dir/
```

Folder will be created. Files will be absolute links to the original folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

using bash script:

```
cd sourcedir
destdir=my-dest-dir-path
for dir in `find . -type d`; do [ "$dir" != "." ] && mkdir -p $destdir/$dir ;done
for file in `find . -type f`; do ln -s $file $destdir/$file; dir
```